# $1 = 0$ by using $f(x) = e^{x}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x) = e^{x}$. Then $f(-x) = e^{-x} = \frac{1}{e^{x}} = \frac{1}{f(x)}$ and $$f(x+y) = e^{x+y} = e^{x} \cdot e^{y} = f(x) \cdot f(y)$$

Then by using the rules for differentiating real functions: $$f'(x) = e^{x} \Rightarrow f'(0) = e^{0} = 1$$

But $$f'(0) = f'(x-x) = (f(x-x))' = (f(x)\cdot f(-x))' = 1' = 0$$

So $$1 = 0$$ What went wrong?

Comment: There's nothing special about $e$ here; the point is that while $f(x)$ and $g(x):=f(x-x)$ have the same value at $x=0$, there is no reason for them to have the same derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: $(f(x)f(-x))' = f(-x)f'(x)-f(x)f'(-x) \neq f'(x-x)$.

Comment: You're confusing evaluating a derivative at a point and taking the derivative of an evaluation of a function at a point. Since evaluating a single variable function at any given value of the variable yields a constant value, taking the derivative of the function evaluated at that value will always give you 0. Again, this is not the same thing as evaluating the derivative of the function, which is a function, at the value desired.

Comment: When you evaluate any function $g(x)$ at a particular value, you are going to get a constant. Differentiating a constant always gives you 0.  But that doesnt imply that the derivative of the function evaluated at a particular value is 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is where you say $f'(x-x) = (f(x)\cdot f(-x))'$; that's simply not so.

A simpler version of the same error:  Say $f(x)=x^2$. Then $f'(2)=4$, but $(f(2))'=4'=0$.

Comment: Or even $f'(0)=(f(0))'$ for any non null function at zero.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is changing where the derivative is taken. On the left, you evaluate the derivative at $0$. On the right, you’re evaluating the function (which gives $1$), then taking the derivative, which gives $0$.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about f(x)=e^x.

The problem with $$f'(0) = f'(x-x) = (f(x-x))' = (f(x)\cdot f(-x))' = 1' = 0$$

is that $f'(0)$ is not the same as $(f(0))'.$

Note that if your function is $f(x)=\sin(x)$, then $f'(0) =\cos(0)=1$ but $(f(0))' = 0'=0$

Regardless of the function f(x), $f(0)$ is a real number not a function.

Thus when you take derivative of $f(0)$, you always get $0$ regardless of what f(x) is.